# useState hook not working in useEffect hook in my react native app

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The below code result in app crashing when `setGeofence(results.rows._array)` is called, if i remove it, it works fine and app does not crash

```js
const [geofence, setGeofence] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "create table if not exists geofence (id text primary key not null, lat text, lng text, note text, radius real, state boolean );",
        [],
        (tx, results) => {}
      );

      tx.executeSql("select * from geofence", [], (tx, results) => {
        setGeofence(results.rows._array);
        console.log("egeo" + results.rows._array.length);
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

But if I put values other than `results.rows._array` it works fine without app crashing

```js
useEffect(() => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "create table if not exists geofence (id text primary key not null, lat text, lng text, note text, radius real, state boolean );",
        [],
        (tx, results) => {}
      );

      tx.executeSql("select * from geofence", [], (tx, results) => {
        setGeofence("Its is working");
        console.log("egeo" + results.rows._array.length);
      });
    });

  }, []);
```

above code worked and does not result in app crashing.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: check if `results is undefined` or `results.rows is undefined`, if you're using typescript, try replace it with `results?.rows?._array`

Comment: @ArutyunEnfendzhyan I didn't see any errors just the app gets closed and keep crashing when opening the app until I remove setGeofence or put some other values in it

Comment: @YeXiaoRain 
results are not undefined as in console.log I am getting values of results.